# What's wrong with this if/else/else if statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
int main(){
unsigned int fstNumb = 0, sndNumb = 0;
cout << "Choose the first number: ";
cin >> fstNumb;
cout << "\nChoose the second number: ";
cin >> sndNumb;
cout << "\nNow click \'m\' to multiply, \'a\' to add or \'d\' to divide: ";
char option = '\0';
cin >> option; cout << "\n\n";
float result;
if (option == 'm'){
    result = fstNumb * sndNumb;
    cout << result;
} 
else if (option == 'a'){
    result = fstNumb + sndNumb;
    cout << result;
}
else if (option == 'd') {
    if (fstNumb || sndNumb == 0)
        cout << "Cannot divide with 0 :/";
    else {
        cout << "You want the " << fstNumb << " or " << sndNumb << " to be divided?\n";
        cout << "Press 1 for " << fstNumb << " or 2 for " << sndNumb;
        char option2 = '\0';
        cin >> option2;
        if (option2 == 1){
            cout << "\nYou chose " << fstNumb;
            cout << "\nWanna divide it by how much?: ";
            unsigned short division;
            cin >> division;
            if (division == 0){
                cout << "\nCannot divide by 0!";
            }
            else{
                result = fstNumb / division;
            }
        }
        else if (option2 == 2){
            cout << "\nYou chose " << sndNumb;
            cout << "\nWanna divide it by how much?: ";
            unsigned short division;
            cin >> division;
            result = sndNumb / division;
        }
        else
            cout << "You must choose one of those 2 numbers!\n";
    }
}
else
    cout << "That's none of the letters I asked you.\n";
```

}

That if `(fstNumb || sndNumb == 0)` always displays even when none of the integers are `0`, what's the problem?
Note that I'm not using boolean variables, but that shouldn't be a problem I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if (fstNumb || sndNumb == 0)` is not the same thing as `if (fstNumb == 0 || sndNumb == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (fstNumb || sndNumb == 0)
```

is as same as

```
if (fstNumb != 0 || sndNumb == 0)
```

Change this part to (if you don't expect answer as 0),

```
if (fstNumb == 0 || sndNumb == 0)
```

But if there is no problem to get 0 as answer,

```
if ( sndNumb == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** Your logic is incorrect. `if (fstNumb || sndNumb == 0)` is the same as `if ( (fstNumb != 0) || (sndNumb == 0) )`, but you want `if (fstNumb == 0 || sndNumb == 0)`. Change it to the latter and it will work as expected.

**To explain why `"Cannot divide with 0 :/"` displays even if neither `fstNumb` nor `sndNumb` is `0`:**

If `fstNumb` is nonzero, then it evaluates as true when treated as a boolean (zero is false; everything else is true). `||` has lower precedence than `==`, so the whole expression evaluates to `fstNumb || (sndNumb == 0)`. When `fstNumb != 0`, that expression is the same as `true || (sndNumb == 0)`, which is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Change condition `if (fstNumb || sndNumb == 0)` to `if (sndNumb == 0)`
Because first number can be `0`.

```
Input  : 0 12 
Answer : 0
```